# Launch4j exe no http requests?

Tags: http, url, request, exe, launch4j

I want to make an http(s) request from my java application.
Everything works fine, also if I run the .jar file.
But as soon as I convert it to .exe (with launch4j) this code doesn't seem to work anymore:

```
try (java.util.Scanner s = new java.util.Scanner(new java.net.URL("https://appsofuse.com/success.php/"+version).openStream())) {
          body=s.useDelimiter("\\A").next();
          System.out.println(body);
          ;}
```

Is there anything I can do about it? I'm very frustrated bc I want to share my application with others :/

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem by copying everything from the java folder to the bundled java path. (not only bin & lib)